# How can I select an radio button after div display block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Here's my code:

**HTML :**

```
<span id="opc1"> <input type="radio" name="radio_relatorio" id="tipo_relA" value="A"> A </span>
<span id="opc2"> <input type="radio" name="radio_relatorio" id="tipo_relS" value="S"> S </span>
```

**Javascript :**

```
 $("select[name=tprel]").change(function() {
    document.getElementById("tpbaixa").selectedIndex = 0;
    muda_label_datas($(this).val());
    if($(this).val() == 18)
    {
        $("#opc2").css("display","block");
        $("#opc1").css("display","none");

        $("#tipo_relS").attr('checked', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#opc2").css("display","none");
        $("#opc1").css("display","block");

        $("#tipo_relS").attr('checked', false);
    } // it's an large function, but that's what matter
   });
```

There's two Radio under an change function, `#tipo_relS` and `#tiporelA`. The radio `#tiporelA` is checked on onload function. When the value of option is 18, the radio `#tiporelA` is display none and `#tiporelS` is display block.

I would need to check this radio button `#tiporelS` while `#tiporelA` is display none, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You description and code do not match! Probably replicate your problem in a fiddle.

Comment: Could you provide the larger context of your code? And what precisely is the behavior you're looking for? What are you checking #tiporelS for?

Comment: as @lshettyl said there's not match between the code you posted and what you ask for.

Comment: Any suggestion of how can I rewrite the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you description and code do not match! Hence, purely based on assumption I came up with this.

- On load `tipo_relA` is checked and `tipo_relS` is hidden.
- On change of select box with name `tprel`, when the value is 18, `tipo_relA` is hidden and `tipo_relS` is shown.
- The shown radio is checked and hidden is unchecked.

Demo:

```js
$("select[name=tprel]").change(function() {

    $("#opc2, #opc1").addClass("hidden");
    $(":radio").prop('checked', false);

    if( $(this).val() == 18) {
        $("#opc2").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#tipo_relS").prop('checked', true);

    } else {
        $("#opc1").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#tipo_relA").prop('checked', true);
    }
}).change();
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="opc1">
    [tipo_relA] <input type="radio" name="radio_relatorio" id="tipo_relA" value="A" />
</span>
<span id="opc2" class="hidden">
    [tipo_relS] <input type="radio" name="radio_relatorio" id="tipo_relS" value="S" />
</span>

<select name="tprel">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah! That's it! But I do use jquery <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @LucasSantos that doesn't matter as long as jQuery is loaded!

Comment: Any suggestion why it doesn't work? How can I fix this? It's simple but nothing works...

Comment: Why _what_ doesn't work? My demo above works well with `jQuery 1.9.1`

Comment: I guess there is another change function running together with this function, but your code works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$("#tipo_relS").attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: Add some HTML to your post so we can see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

The trick is here you have to unhide the radio button, click or check it then rehide it all in the same function.  The user won't see the change but it will allow the browser to select the value and would be fast enough that it will be invisible to the user.